# Filter data from object inside another object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript1.8

I have a situation like this:

```
var first = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 3},
    {'id': 4}
];
var second = [
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 4}
];
```

I would like to filter all elements from "first" where the id is inside "second".
I am trying something like this:

```
var result = first.filter((x:any) => second.id.indexOf(x.id) < 0);
```

I tried with foreach, but it did not work.
The result I would like to get is this:

```
var first = [
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 4}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) combination.

Try the following:

```js
const first = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 3},
    {'id': 4}
];

const second = [
    {'id': 2},
    {'id': 4}
];

const result1 = first.filter(e => second.some(s => s.id === e.id));
console.log('includes', result1);

const result2 = first.filter(e => !second.some(s => s.id === e.id));
console.log('not includes', result2);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @AndreNaves Great, happy to help! Feel free to accept as the answer or upvote if it solves your problem. Appreciate.